# Filling an array with integers

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to fill an array with numbers 1111 to 8888, with each integer in the number being between  1 and 8 in c++. However, when I run it, it's only outputting large negative numbers indicating an error. I honestly have clue what the error is so it would be appreciated if you could help me out. Thanks!

```
    int fillArray()
    {
    int arrayPosition;  
    int guesses[4096];

arrayPosition = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
      for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
        for (int k = 1; k <= 8; k++)
          for (int m = 1; m <= 8; m++)
          {
           guesses[arrayPosition] = ((i * 1000) + (j * 100) + (k *10) + m);
           cout << guesses[arrayPosition];
                   arrayPosition++;   
           }

return guesses[4096];
    }
```

Comment: Where is your output statement that is causing the problem?

Comment: sorry about that, fixed it :)

Answer (score 4):

Your return type is wrong. `int fillArray()`, but you're trying to return an `int[4096]` that was declared on the stack... What you're actually doing with `return guesses[4096];` is returning the first memory location *after* your array in memory, which is probably just garbage, hence your issue with large negative numbers.

You can fix it by allocating your array in the heap, and returning a pointer to the start of that array:

```
int * fillArray()
{
  int arrayPosition;  
  int * guesses = new int[4096];

  // other stuff stays the same...

  return guesses;
}
```

However, since your function is called **fillArray**, it would make more sense to pass in an array and fill it rather than creating the array in the function. (If you wanted to do that, might call it something like `make_1_to_8_array` instead, to make it more clear that you're constructing something that will need to be deleted later.) Giving an `int*` as the first argument would allow you to pass in the base address of your array that you want filled:

```
void fillArray(int * guesses)
{
  int arrayPosition;  

  // other stuff stays the same...

}
```

Or, if you want to verify that the you're using an array of the exact size:

```
void fillArray(int (&guesses)[4096])
{
  int arrayPosition;  

  // other stuff stays the same...

}
```

Note that the function now returns `void` since you just update the array that was passed in, and you don't need to return anything new.

Comment: Sorry I dont completely follow. I'm just learning about arrays now so I'm very new at this.

Comment: Array in C and C++ are zero-based, so if you make an array of size `4096`, then the valid indices are `0` thru `4095`. Your function is declared to return an `int`, and you're returning the single integer at `guesses[4096]`, which is actually outside the bounds of the array you declared (since it only goes up to `4095`).

Comment: Ouch, this is horrible horrible practice compared with just passing in the buffer to be filled...

Comment: Thank you so much Dao, I completely understand now and it works perfectly!

Comment: Just to have it said... I'd suggest using a vector, so that you can simply return it, don't have to use pointers and no worries about leaking memory with new/delete.

Comment: @ebyrob - I think it's fine to allocate something in a function and return it as long as it's very clear who is in charge of the memory. However, in this case I'd say you're definitely right since the function name suggests you should just be filling an existing array, not creating a new one. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DaoWen I got thinking about this.  What if an exception is thrown between `new []` and `return` during "other stuff"?  Wouldn't the allocated block need to be tied into destructor cleanup very very near the moment of creation?  I could see very carefully passing a `**` and filling that if the caller does things just right, but even that might be dicey in some cases?

Comment: @ebyrob - If an exception occurred, I'd probably want to catch it, delete the array, and re-throw the exception. But, frankly, it's headaches like this that lead me to choose a garbage-collected languages when I have the choice. I actually don't understand what you're saying with "[tying] into destructor cleanup very near the moment of creation."

Answer (score 3):

Your `for`-loops look correct, but your array handling is off, as is highlighted by other answers.

It is more usual in C++ to use `std::vector` and to pass this in *by reference* as an argument. This saves you having to handle memory allocations and deallocations. Here's an example, including the output in the `for`-loops:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int fillArray(std::vector<int>& guesses)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
            for (int k = 1; k <= 8; k++)
                for (int m = 1; m <= 8; m++)
                {
                    guesses.push_back((i * 1000) + (j * 100) + (k * 10) + m);
                    std::cout << guesses.back() << std::endl;
                }

    return guesses.back();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> guesses;
    std::cout << fillArray(guesses) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your array locally then attempting to return it.  If you try printing (to debug) out the result of your array prior to returning, you will see it is ok.  However, once you return, the array is no linger valid.  Try passing in an array into your function instead.

Comment: @Tribse The description may not be 100%, but the fix works nonetheless and it's actually good practice.

Comment: Yea I put the cout to debug to see what the values were , they should be 111,1112, etc but they were large negative numbers. the return is returning that to another function, sorry if i wasnt clear.

Comment: @Tribse, I believe the goal was to return an array, as indicated by the return type (int *).  However, they are returning garbage - as you indicated.  The appropriate way to achieve their goal is to intead pass in the array and populate it.

Comment: @Tribse looks like you voted down the incorrect analysis despite a correct solution.  I voted down the incorrect solution despite a good analysis.  To each his own I guess...